# Javascript setTimeout function issue

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, setinterval

I have a test page http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/test.php, and here is the relevant script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slide_out(){
    $('#red-block').animate({
        marginLeft: -278
    }, 500);
    $('#yellow-block').animate({
        marginTop: -316
    }, 500);    
    $('#gray-block').animate({
        marginLeft: 278
    }, 500, function(){
        $('#three-color-container').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#three-color-container-new').fadeIn(500, function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){slide_in()}, 4000);
            });
        }); 
    }); 
}
function slide_in(){
    $('#three-color-container-new').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#three-color-container').fadeIn(500, function(){
            $('#red-block, #yellow-block, #gray-block').animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 0
            }, 500, function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
            });
        });
    });
}

window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
</script>
```

Now the red yellow gray color blocks slide like this:
out, in, out, in, out and then flash(which is not what i want), only work for two and a half loops.
If I set the timer from 4000 to 6000, it works at most 3 loops, and then breaks also.

I want it to be out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in...... forever
I guess the problem might be in the setTimeout function.

Comment: Quick tip: `setTimeout(function(){slide_in()})` same as `setTimeout(slide_in)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#red-block, #yellow-block, #gray-block` animation is calling that setTimeout function three times, causing the entire process to be triplicated every time it runs, eventually causing a conflict.

The best solution to this without changing too much code would be to do this:

```
$('#red-block, #yellow-block').animate({marginLeft:0,marginTop:0},500);
$('#gray-block').animate({marginLeft:0,marginTop:0,500,function() {setTimeout(slide_out,4000);});
```

Comment: in which function? do you have a full script